# How to use 'useFormState` to get response of server and handle errors in form?

Tags: next.js, next.js14

Based on https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/authentication, I am using the following snippet of code:

```
// app/login/page.tsx
'use client'
 
import { authenticate } from '@/app/lib/actions'
import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from 'react-dom'
 
export default function Page() {
  const [errorMessage, dispatch] = useFormState(authenticate, undefined)
 
  return (
    <form action={dispatch}>
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required />
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required />
      <div>{errorMessage && <p>{errorMessage}</p>}</div>
      <LoginButton />
    </form>
  )
}
 
function LoginButton() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus()
 
  return (
    <button aria-disabled={pending} type="submit">
      Login
    </button>
  )
}
```

It will show response error message correctly in the form, but I want when the user start writing anything in the form, clear error message. to do that, I changed the code to the following one:

```
'use client'

import { authenticate } from '@/app/lib/actions'
import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from 'react-dom'
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function Page() {
  const [errorMessage, dispatch] = useFormState(authenticate, undefined);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState(errorMessage);
  useEffect(() => {
    setErrorMsg(errorMessage);
  }, [errorMessage]);

  const clearError = () => {
    setErrorMsg(null);
  }

  return (
      <form action={dispatch}>
        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required onChange={clearError} />
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required onChange={clearError} />
        <div>{errorMsg && <p>{errorMsg}</p>}</div>
        <LoginButton />
      </form>
  )
}

function LoginButton() {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus()

  return (
      <button aria-disabled={pending} type="submit">
        Login
      </button>
  )
}
```

It will work once, but after that the state of `errorMessage` will not effect on `errorMsg` so it will not work.
Could you please guide me how I can handle error messages (showing error in the form and clear it when user start typing), with or without using `useEffect` and `useState`. Please note that I am trying to keep using `useFormState` as it is mentioned many times in many places in NextJs documentations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you attach a server action to a form, that form is a server form which can work without javascript in the browser. so your validation logic in server form must work without javascript.

your form is talking to the server and if the server generates an error, you want to send this down to the client and display it. so, that error is generated on the server when you submit the form.

One way is when you have error and when u detect user type in, you can remove this div:

```
<div>{errorMessage && <p>{errorMessage}</p>}</div>
```

or you set a ref on the errorMessage div and remove the textContent when you detect user input:

```
errorRef.current.textContent = ''
```

Comment: Yes, it is server side. the problem is, I can use useEffect and useState to handle clientError message, but seems as the response error is not changing (for example it is always "invalid input"), so state of 'errorMessage' won't change and it won't update 'errorMsg' (because useEffect will not trigger). I need to show error after getting error from server after form submit, clear it on user input and re-add when getting same/another server error on next submit.